# How to stop iterating using itertools.islice when EOF is reached

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to use  `itertools.islice(self._f, 0, 100, None)` to read in a file piece by piece (in blocks of 100 lines) as follows:

```
f = open('test.dat', 'r')

while (some condition I look for):
    f = open(fileName, 'r') 

    x = itertools.islice(f, 0, 100, None)

    doSomethingWithX(x)
```

My problem is, I do not know how long the file is and I am looking for a condition to stop the while loop when the end of the file is reached. But I cannot figure out how it is done.

EDIT: Ok, I see the difficulty. Maybe I should reformulate the question when the itertools.islice is capsuled in a class like here:

```
class reader:
    def __init__()
        self._f = open('test.dat', 'r')

    def getNext():
        return itertools.islice(self._f, 0, 100, None)




R = reader()
while (some condition I look for):
   x = R.getNext()
   doSomethingWithX(x)
```

Comment: Could you please include in your question, whether you are trying to iterate over `lines` or `bytes`?

Comment: I have edited my code to fetch 100 lines per iteration. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind getting list slices, you can use `iter`:

```
with  open(filename, 'r')  as f:
    for x in iter(lambda: list(itertools.islice(f, 100)), []):
        doSomethingWithX(x)
```

Not sure which file you are using as you have `f = ..` twice and  have `self_.f` in there too.

Using your edited code:

```
class reader:
    def __init__(self):
        self._f = open('out.csv', 'r')

    def getNext(self):
        return itertools.islice(self._f, 100)

R = reader()
import itertools
for x in iter(lambda: list(R.getNext()),[]):
    print(x)
```

using a test file with the following and your class code using  `itertools.islice(self._f, 2)`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

outputs:

```
In [15]: R = reader()

In [16]: import itertools

In [17]: for x in iter(lambda: list(R.getNext()),[]):
   ....:         print(x)
   ....:     
['1\r\n', '2\r\n']
['3\r\n', '4\r\n']
['5\r\n', '6\r\n']
['7\r\n', '8\r\n']
['9\r\n', '10']
```

Comment: @andi, the answer will applies, this will take 100 lines at a time until you have exhausted the iterator i.e got to the end of the file, the only issue is whether you want a list of what exactly you want to do with x

Comment: Maybe I am to stu*** to see it :( I will give it a shot, but might take a while :D. Thanks already for your time.

Comment: using `[]` with iter is a sentinel value, we call list on the islice object so when we get to the end there will be an empty list so the loop ends, you will get 100 lines in a list each iteration until the end

Comment: but what if the file has 150 lines?

Comment: I do not get it to work in the class, sorry. Would you be able to include it in the class? Sorry for the troubles.

Comment: if it has 150, you will get a list of 100 lines then a  list of 50 lines

Comment: Okay, but lets say instead of blocks sized 100 we say blocks with size of 2. Could I modify the code such that the output becomes 1,2 ... 3,4 ... 5,6? This is what I would need.

Comment: just replace 100 with 2, you should make it an attribute and then pass it in when you instantiate a instance, I used `2` in my example

Comment: The EOF question is related to this one. If I could say something like self._f == EOF than I could also catch this exception before doing `return itertools.islice(self._f, 0, 100, None)`. This is what I need ... :S

Comment: I think you might be overcomplicating the issue, what are you going to do when you get to the end of the file? Every slice you get means you are not at the EOF, when the loop ends you are. There is no way using islice that you can tell the file has reached the end until you consume the lines and there is none left, if you want to know when you are within `n` lines of the end, that is possible with  a little more logic. This code does exactly what your question asks so unless there is something you are not including then maybe you are misunderstanding something

Comment: This will tell you when you get to the EOF using tell but it won't work using islice http://pastebin.com/VTguveYV

Answer (score 0):

So what I was looking for was something like this:

```
class reader:
    def __init__()
        self._f = open('test.dat', 'r')

        self._f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)   # find EOF
        self._EOF = self._f.tell()     
        self._f.seek(0)                # go back to beginning

    def getNext():
        if self._f.tell() != self._EOF:
            x = np.genfromtxt(itertools.islice(self._f, 0, self._chunkSizes, None), dtype=np.float64)
            return x
        else:
            return []




R = reader()
x = R.getNext()
while (x != []):
   doSomethingWithX(x)

   x = R.getNext()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `readline` method to easily process the chunks of 100 lines. Do as follows:

```
def read_chunks(f, chunks=100):
    block = True
    while block:
        block = [f.readline() for i in range(chunks)]
        block = list(filter(None, block))
        yield block


with open("filename") as f:
    for lines in read_chunks(f):
        print(len(lines), lines)
```