# Find out if file pointer is at EOF in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find out whether my file pointer is at the EOF like in this example code: (EDITED)

```
f = open("test.dat")

someFunctionDoingStuffOn_f(f)

if f == EOF:         # to keep something like this would be important in my case
    print "EOF reached"
else:
    print "Not EOF"
```

But I do not know if there is anything like this available in Python.

I have edited the question by adding someFunctionDoingStuffOn_f(f), because it might be that I do not know what happened with f before hand. This excludes some approaches.

Comment: `for line in f:use line`, I am not sure why you think you need an `EOF`, when python gets to the end of the file the loop will end

Comment: `f.readline()` returns an empty string at EOF. Or you can try and seek to the end with `f.seek()` and see if `f.tell()` changed compared to before.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Sounds promising, could you explain that a bit more in detail?

Comment: @andi: start with the [documentation for the methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek); perhaps seek to the end of the file (`f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)`), store the position with `f.tell()`, then seek to the start again and compare `f.tell()` calls with the end position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on martijns comment you can use the `tell` but I really don't see how it is going to make a difference:

```
import os

R.f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
n = R.f.tell()
R.f.seek(0)

while R.f.tell() < n:
    line = R.f.readline()
    print(line)
    print("Not at EOF")
print("At EOF")
```

Where `R.f` is the file object from your class in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039644/how-to-stop-iterating-using-itertools-islice-when-eof-is-reached/32039718?noredirect=1#32039718) but you cannot use tell in the same way using islice.

Or using it using if's to be more like the logic in your question:

```
import os

R.f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
n = R.f.tell()
R.f.seek(0)

while True:
    if R.f.tell() != n:
        line = R.f.readline()
        print(line)
        print("Not at EOF")
    else:
         print("At EOF")
         break
```

Comment: This might work...I will try it tomorrow morning! Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: No worries, I think there may be a link in the chain we are missing but hopefully it brings you a little closer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my programming skills are not so great :S

Comment: No prob, sometimes it is as hard to describe the problem as it is to conquer it.

Comment: GREAT! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that usually should not be done. However it might be reasonable in your case. Please provide some context if my suggestions are not applicable.

1.

```
with open("test.dat", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something_with_line(line)
```

2.

```
with open("test.dat", "r") as f:
    whole_file = file.read()
```

After edit:

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html. You might be able to use `.read(maxbytes)` to do what you want.

Comment: I am just looking for something that can tell me in an if clause wheather f is EOF without changing f.